# UIImagePickerController differences from iPhone and iPad woes

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, orientation, device

I have an app designed for iPhone that makes use of the UIImagePickerController.

The app run in landscape only up until the image picker comes into view in its default portrait.

Problem 1:
On the iPhone when I rotate the device to portrait to view the image library the image picker view seems to do a flip as if rotating from landscape to portrait?

Problem 2:
I get the dreaded warning Using two-stage rotation animation. To use the smoother single-stage animation, this application must remove two-stage method implementations.

Problem 3.
on the iPad when selecting an image the image picker is dismissed and the view is back in landscape but ...... if I then do anything that requires alert view or the keyboard they appear as if the device is in portrait?  This does not happen on the iPhone???

I know problem 2 is a long running issue but please can anyone help with problems 1 & 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

number 3 resolved :-)

"The keyboard will show up in the orientation of the statusbar, which doesn't always change with rotations for some reason. So if you want to display that view only in landscape set [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft; or whichever orientation you want to prefer in your viewWillAppear method."