# Photo Picker app has same issue!

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, landscape, portrait

This is related to my previous thread, but opened a new one here as it involves Apple's own sample code.

Open the sample code and modify the app so it will display in landscape and add a textfield to the view.

Run the app and open the image picker, select an image and you will be returned to the previous screen in landscape as you would expect.

Now tap the text field and see the keyboard scroll into view....in portrait mode?

This happens on the iPad not the iPhone, what gives????

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096778/uiimagepickercontroller-differences-from-iphone-and-ipad-woes)

Comment: Same issue? Previous post? You will have to be more specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIImagePickerController differences from iPhone and iPad woes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096778/uiimagepickercontroller-differences-from-iphone-and-ipad-woes)

Comment: If you need to clarify the original question, edit it.  Don't create a new question just to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer on this forum :-)

"The keyboard will show up in the orientation of the statusbar, which doesn't always change with rotations for some reason. So if you want to display that view only in landscape set [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft; or whichever orientation you want to prefer in your viewWillAppear method."

Although why it does not do this on the iPhone ????